# Angular Payment method

Tags: json, angular, payment-gateway

How to fetch Page Redirection Code (Json) in Angular?

I tried a lot but it is of no use, I'm going expecting someone experience who could guide me on this

Comment: Please elaborate. What have you tried so far? Where is is the problem? What is the end result? Do you mean to fetch http and after response navigate user to some other page? What do you mean by redirection code?

Comment: is it the page after you make payment etc payment response page, since Angular is client side, its need server side to handled these scenario

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.